# Lua __pairs implementation in C

Tags: lua

i have implemented a simple persistent key-value memory in C. For this memory i implemented a Lua 5.3 binding with the following API:

```lua
    local store = require("store")

    local db = store.open("/test.db")
    db["a"] = "first"
    db["b"] = "second"
    db["c"] = "third"

    print(db["a"])
    print(db["b"])
    print(db["c"])
```

db is a user-data object

now i want to implement the __pairs metamethod in C, so that the following iteration is possible:

```lua
    for i,v in pairs(db) do
        print(i, v)
    end
```

But I can't find any examples of this for C.
Has anyone ever done this before and can give me an example?

Comment: To start with, you'll need to make sure you understand what the Lua statement `for ... in` actually does with the list returned by `pairs`, `ipairs`, etc.

Comment: Lua is open source and implemented in C. why don't you take a look into Lua's source code?  https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/45948e7e55c753cf0e370b251ac1d4e7f3aabedd/lbaselib.c

Comment: @aschepler: Lua is no problem to understand ... but the C API is sometime a litle bit strange to me.

Comment: @Piglet: Thx, but the Code is very heavy... i found a solution in the lfs (lua file system) module